# How can I validate payloads from GitHub webhooks in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, request, sha, github-webhook

I've realized auto-deploying of my Flask app on the server by Github webhooks, but I cannot adapt Ruby script specified in the [manual](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/#validating-payloads-from-github)  to Python 3 to validate the POST-request. I've tried this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from hmac import HMAC, compare_digest
from hashlib import sha1

app = Flask(__name__)

def verify_signature(req):
     received_sign = req.headers.get('X-Hub-Signature').split('sha1=')[-1].strip()
     secret = 'my_secret_string'.encode()
     expected_sign = HMAC(key=secret, msg=req.data, digestmod=sha1).hexdigest()
     return compare_digest(received_sign, expected_sign)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if verify_signature(request):
            do_smth()
            return 'Successfully', 200
        return 'Forbidden', 403
    return 'Not allowed', 405
```

Also I tried other variants with sha1(...).hexdigest() and compare_digest() from secrets package, but received signature always differs.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Worked the first time running , well done

Comment: SHA-256 is now recommended over SHA-1.

Answer (score 3):

### Use SHA-256 instead of SHA-1

Instead of SHA-1 [GitHub recommends](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#delivery-headers) using the more secure SHA-256.

Changed your code respectively for convenience.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from hmac import HMAC, compare_digest
from hashlib import sha256

app = Flask(__name__)

def verify_signature(req):
     received_sign = req.headers.get('X-Hub-Signature-256').split('sha256=')[-1].strip()
     secret = 'my_secret_string'.encode()
     expected_sign = HMAC(key=secret, msg=req.data, digestmod=sha256).hexdigest()
     return compare_digest(received_sign, expected_sign)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if verify_signature(request):
            do_smth()
            return 'Successfully', 200
        return 'Forbidden', 403
    return 'Not allowed', 405
```

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the code. Now it works well.

Comment: This should be an `EDIT` to your initial question and not a one sentence answering yourself.